# Display only a single figure when in draft mode

Tags: graphics, floats, draft

How can I enable a single figure when in draft mode?

I am working on a large document (thesis) containing many figures. Some of these figures are large, resulting in long compile times. I can fix this by switching the document to draft mode.

However, when I am adding a figure, and associated discussion, I will generally want to see the figure in full, in place. Also, since I'm adding something new I'll often be re-compiling minor changes to see how it looks.

What I would like to do is to have the document set to draft mode (figures not being loaded) but have the "active" figure displayed until I'm finished with it. I don't know of any way to do this. is it possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What I usually do is work on the figure in a separate document, using the `standalone` class, and then include it into the main document using the `standalone` package.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just set `draft=false` for the picture you want to be shown anyway:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[draft=false,width=50pt]{example-image-b}

\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent!!, very natural.

Answer (score 7):

Create a macro `\includegraphicsfinal` (say) which will always be set in `final` mode, regardless of whether your document is set in `final` or `draft` mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\includegraphicsfinal}[2][]{{%
  \Gin@draftfalse% Turn draft mode off
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}}% Include graphic
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a}

\includegraphicsfinal[width=50pt]{example-image-b}

\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

Note the grouping inside `\includegraphicsfinal` which provides a localized scope for the change to `\ifGin@draft`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [`draftfigure`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/draftfigure) to get the same result and modify the display of the switched off figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[allfiguresdraft]{draftfigure}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[draft=false,width=50pt]{example-image-b}

\setdf{content={This figure is switched off.}}
\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

[image]